# Как отредактировать сообщение телеграмм спомощью модуля pyTelegramBotAPI(telebot)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telebot

Как отредактировать сообщение телеграмм спомощью модуля pyTelegramBotAPI(telebot)?

Comment: Использовать соответствующий метод
`edit_message_text('Edit test', chat_id=CHAT_ID, message_id=msg.message_id)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
bot.edit_message_text(chat_id, message_id, inline_message_id, text, parse_mode, disable_web_page_preview, reply_markup)
```

Подробнее:
https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#editmessagetext